# How to generate a syntax for each key of a dictionary?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I'm trying to generate a syntax for each key of a dictionary according to the values of the same dictionary. Below is my code:

```
my_dict={'key1':('a','b','c','d'), 'key2':('e','f','c','h'}
global_syntax=""
for key, val in my_dict.iteritems():
    if val[2][0]='c':
        mysyntax(key)

def write_to_file (syntax_to_write):
    global global_syntax
    global_syntax=global_syntax+str(syntax_to_write)

def mysyntax(key):
    my_variable=key
    my_syntax="""
do all stuff + {key} + {val}
""".format(\
key=key,\
val=val[2][0])
    write_to_file(mysyntax.encode('utf8'))
```

so here, in the file generated I would like:

> do all stuff key1 c
>
> do all stuff key2 c

but when I run this, this is telling me that mysyntax is not defined. Do we have any specificity because I read the data from a dictionary?

Comment: define your function mysyntax(key) before your for loop wher you are calling it

Comment: This code has syntax error(s).

Comment: mysyntax does not encode method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# define your function before you are calling it
def mysyntax(key):
    my_variable=key
    my_syntax="\"" # to use  quotation marks inside quotation marks use "\"" instead of """

my_dict={'key1':('a','b','c','d'), 'key2':('e','f','c','h')}
global_syntax=""
for key, val in my_dict.items():
    if val[2][0]=='c': # to Equality Check Difference use == instead of =
        mysyntax(key)
```